# Actionsheet buttons do not respond when using showInView

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uiactionsheet, ios6.1

I have this code on my program

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *saveMessageBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[saveMessageBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveMessageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(saveMessage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[saveMessageBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 49, 30)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:saveMessageBtn];
}

-(IBAction)saveMessage:(id)sender{


UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send Now",@"Non Recurring",@"Recurring", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 0){
    NSLog(@"Send Now");
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalNonRecurring" sender:self];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 2){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalRecurring" sender:self];
}
else{
NSLog(@"Cancel Clicked");
    }
}
```

as you can see in the code, it supposed to perform a segue or do 'NSLog' when a particular button clicked.

But when I click a button, it does not perform what I want it to do, instead it displays this message in the debug area..

`Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].`

By the way, I am using a `UINavigationController` that is inside a `UITabBarController`.
Anyone that has a great idea how to fix this? your help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UIActionSheetDelegate` delegate in .h file and try like this then it'l work.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send Now",@"Non Recurring",@"Recurring", nil];
    actionSheet.delegate = self;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: yeah, it work! Thanks a lot. Everybody must give you a plus, I regret I don't have enough reputation to give you one @Sunny

Comment: I just did. Thanks again. :)